# Bluebird promise multi-level

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I am struggling to figure out how to have multiple levels of promises execute asynchronously.  I have searched through the documentation but most promise libraries have you waiting for all promises to do some logic or one then the next.  I need an aspect of both of this.  I wrote up a quick demonstration of what i'm trying to achieve.

The general idea behind this is I have 4 functions which I need to call.  A & B can be called right away at the same time.  C is dependent on B's return.  Then I need all three (A,B,C) to compute D.  How would I structure this?

I tried to draw the general flow chart here:

```
A ->   -> D
B -> C ->
```

---

Sample code:

```
var bluebird = require('bluebird');

function a(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('a called');
    return 'a';
  },1000);
}

function b(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('b called');
    return 'b message';
  },1000);
}

function c(bMessage){
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('c called');
    return 'c set in motion';
  },1000);
}

function d(aMessage, bMessage, cMessage){
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('prmoises: called: ' + aMessage + bMessage + cMessage);
    return 'this the end';
  },1000);
}

function test(){
    // what goes here?
}

test();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with [returning promises from your asynchronous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) instead of just calling `setTimeout`. Best just drop the `setTimeout` completely and use `Promise.delay(…).then(…)`.

Then use `then` for single dependencies and [`Promise.join`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.join.html) for multiple ones. Don't build long chains, store the promise for each result that you need in a variable:

```
function test(){
    var aPromise = a();
    var bPromise = b();
    var cPromise = bPromise.then(c);
    return Promise.join(aPromise, bPromise, cPromise, d);
}
```

See also the related question [How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572).

Comment: Thank you, this answered all my questions! And the settimeouts were just for illustrating my problem